# Dynamic name for react-final-form Field

Tags: react-final-form

I have 2 forms. When I choose an option on 1st form, the 2nd form is added to the page with the parameters retrieved from backend. Now how can I set the parameter names as react-final-form Field names?

I could not find a way to do this. Where to pass the parameter names?

```
  <Form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    validate={validate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the FinalForm like

```
<FinalFieldArrayForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmitTemplate} fieldsFromServer={parameters} />
```

and FinalForm is

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form'
import arrayMutators from 'final-form-arrays'
import { FieldArray } from 'react-final-form-arrays'

import "./styles.css";

const FinalForm = ({onSubmit, fieldsFromServer}) => (
  <Form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    mutators={{
      // potentially other mutators could be merged here
      ...arrayMutators
    }}
    render={({
      handleSubmit,
      form: {
        mutators: { push, pop }
      },
      pristine,
      form,
      submitting,
      values
    }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="buttons">
          <button type="button" onClick={() => push('records', undefined)}>+</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => pop('records')}>-</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={form.reset} disabled={submitting || pristine}>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <FieldArray name="records">
        { ({fields}) => (
          <div>
          {fields.map( (name, index) => (
            <div key={`${name}.${index}`}>
              <label>{index + 1}</label>
              {fieldsFromServer.map( param => <Field key={`${name}.${param}`} name={`${name}.${param}`} component="input" placeholder={`${name}.${param}`} /> )}
              <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>-</button>
              <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.insert(index+1)}>+</button>
            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
        )}
        </FieldArray>
        <div className="buttons">
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting || pristine}>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
      </form>
    )}
  />
)

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<FinalForm onSubmit={() => (<div/>)} fieldsFromServer={["firstName", "lastName"]} />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

React Final Form calls your `onSubmit` function with the values from all the fields in your form. It's totally up to you to transmit the values to your server.

If you're asking how to build the second form, you just add the fields you need to add. So, say you got back from the server that you needed three fields: `[ 'name', 'startTime', 'endTime' ]`. You'd just loop through that array and add the fields.

```
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>({handleSubmit}) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {fieldsFromServer.map(fieldName => (
      <div key={fieldName}>
        <label>{fieldName}</label>
        <Field name={fieldName} component="input"/>
      </div>
    ))}
  </form>
)}<Form>
```

Does that help? You don't have to "pass parameters to the form", you just add the `Field` components that you need.